# React + NodeJs Fetch issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am trying to fetch the following results of my api (which is working well)
http://localhost:5000/api/continents

```
{"data":[{"continentId":3,"CName":"Atlantis"},{"continentId":2,"CName":"Devias"},{"continentId":1,"CName":"Lorencia"}]}
```

into a react component (a simple array to begin with).

Endpoint code extracted from **server.js**:

```
app.get('/api/continents', (req, res) => {
    connection.query(SELECT_ALL_CONTINENTS_QUERY, (err, results) => {
        if(err){
            return res.send(err)
        }
        else{
            return res.json({
                data: results
            })
        }
    });
});
```

Here is my **continents.js** code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './continents.css';

class Continents extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            continents: []
        }
    }

    ComponentDidMount() {
        fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/continents')
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(continents => this.setState({continents}, () => console.log('Continents fetched..', continents)));
    }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Continents</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Continents;
```

And here is the **App.js** code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Continents from './components/continents/continents';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h1 className="App-title">Developed with NodeJS + React</h1>
        </header>
        <Continents />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**Issue:**

**continents** array is empty. No data fetched. However, there are no errors. I would very much appreciate if someone could guide me in the right direction to solve this. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ComponentDidMount` is a function so it shouldn't be capitalized it should be: `componentDidMount`.

And you're passing the incorrect value to the `setState` method, you should pass `{continents: continents.data}` instead of the `continents` object itself.

The corrected code:

```
componentDidMount() {
    fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/continents')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(continents => this.setState({continents: continents.data}));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@Razvan Can you please correct name of your **componentDidMount** method. It should be **componentDidMount** not *ComponentDidMount*. C must be lowercase.

Answer (score 1):

I think the data structure coming back from your API service call contains a `data` key. Try changing your setState to:

```
this.setState({continents: continents.data})
```

If that does not fix it, I'd double check the shape of the data structures you are passing around because the logic seems correct.

Comment: Thanks, there was also a problem with the spelling for componentDidMount() method.

Answer (score 0):

fetch has issues on certain browsers. We faced issues with Samsung Native Browser all iPhone ios11 safari browsers.. The fix we applied is adding the credentials
fetch('/users', {
  credentials: 'same-origin'
})

Below copied from https://github.com/github/fetch#sending-cookies

•   Firefox 39-60
•   Chrome 42-67
•   Safari 10.1-11.1.2
If you target these browsers, it's advisable to always specify credentials: 'same-origin' explicitly with all fetch requests instead of relying on the default:
fetch('/users', {
  credentials: 'same-origin'
})